# SSO for Salesforce android app in Google workspace(as a service provider)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, salesforce

[image]Google as a identity provider I am trying to achieve Single Sign-On (SSO) for Salesforce android app. Need help on choosing the authentication methods(Ex : SAML, OAuth2.0).

Documentation for the authentication methods will be of great help

Comment: Google suggest using SAML in such cases (https://workspace.google.com/learn-more/gsuite-expands-identity-services.html). Salesforce is already pre-integrated (https://support.google.com/a/answer/6194938). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for taking out your time to look at this @Sergiusz. For Salesforce web login  (SSO) we have followed steps mentioned in https://support.google.com/a/answer/6194938#zippy=%2Cstep-set-up-google-as-a-saml-identity-provider-idp and works well.

If you could help me to know how to download a iDP certificate for Salesforce android app under  Apps -> Web and mobile apps. So that we can go ahead and set up the SSO.
Thanks again for looking at this

Answer (score 1):

I can see you were asking how to download the certificate from the IdP (I am unable to comment on the question by the way). You can download it from Admin console > Security > Set up Single Sign On for SAML applications and download the certificate your app is using from there.